# How to save the mysql result to html from the shell prompt

Tags: html, mysql, shell, sed

i execute the below mysql query from mu shell promt

`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p  -H -e  'show processlist;' > test.html`

so now the html file having the table as below

```
<TABLE BORDER=1>
    <TR>
        <TH>Id</TH>
        <TH>User</TH>
        <TH>Host</TH>
        <TH>db</TH>
        <TH>Command</TH>
        <TH>Time</TH>
        <TH>State</TH>
        <TH>Info</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>1</TD>
        <TD>root</TD>
        <TD>localhost</TD>
        <TD>NULL</TD>
        <TD>Sleep</TD>
        <TD>1357</TD>
        <TD></TD>
        <TD>NULL</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>7</TD>
        <TD>root</TD>
        <TD>localhost</TD>
        <TD>NULL</TD>
        <TD>Query</TD>
        <TD>0</TD>
        <TD>NULL</TD>
        <TD>show processlist</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

which means it's saving as a single line, but i need as follows each `<tr></tr>` in a single line

```
<TABLE BORDER=1>
    <TR>
        <TH>Id</TH>
        <TH>User</TH>
        <TH>Host</TH>
        <TH>db</TH>
        <TH>Command</TH>
        <TH>Time</TH>
        <TH>State</TH>
        <TH>Info</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>1</TD>
        <TD>root</TD>
        <TD>localhost</TD>
        <TD>NULL</TD>
        <TD>Sleep</TD>
        <TD>1357</TD>
        <TD></TD>
        <TD>NULL</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>7</TD>
        <TD>root</TD>
        <TD>localhost</TD>
        <TD>NULL</TD>
        <TD>Query</TD>
        <TD>0</TD>
        <TD>NULL</TD>
        <TD>show processlist</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

for try a sed command

Comment: sorry but see no difference between your 2 sample (first nor second are on a "one line" as mentionned)

Comment: i meant first sample as <table><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr></table> (all are in one line),                                                   second sample as like below                                               <table><br>                                                                     <tr><td></td></tr> <br>                                                               <tr><td></td></tr>    <br>                                                                  </table>